How to modify lmer(Yield ~ Env + (Env | Name) to get variance parameter for each level of Env and variance for random-intercept of Name
I am using a dataset from the sommer package in R, where Env is a factor of 3 levels and Name is also a factor.
library(lme4)
library(sommer)

data(DT_example)
DT <- DT_example

mod_a <- lmer(Yield ~ Env + (Env | Name), data = DT)
print(VarCorr(mod_a), comp = "Variance")

 Groups   Name        Variance Cov          
 Name     (Intercept) 15.9918               
          EnvCA.2012   8.9229  -9.820       
          EnvCA.2013  10.9479  -9.626  3.829
 Residual              4.3863 

mod_b <- lmer(Yield ~ Env + (0 + Env | Name), data = DT)
print(VarCorr(mod_b), comp = "Variance")

 Groups   Name       Variance Cov          
 Name     EnvCA.2011 15.9930               
          EnvCA.2012  5.2743   6.172       
          EnvCA.2013  7.6897   6.366  0.375
 Residual             4.3862



mod_c <- lmer(Yield ~ Env + (1 | Name/Env), data = DT)
print(VarCorr(mod_c), comp = "Variance")

 Groups   Name        Variance
 Env:Name (Intercept) 5.1732  
 Name     (Intercept) 3.6819  
 Residual             4.3662 

In mod_a, there is not variance parameter for the first level of Env. In mod_b, there is no random-intercept variance. If I understand correctly, mod_c is reasonable only when Env is nested in Name. There is only one variance parameter returned for Env.
In sommer, I can obtain variance parameter of random-intercept for Name and varance for each level of Env through:
mod_d <- mmer(Yield ~ Env, random = ~ Name + vsr(dsr(Env), Name),
              rcov = ~ units, data = DT, verbose = FALSE)
summary(mod_d)
============================================================
         Multivariate Linear Mixed Model fit by REML         
**********************  sommer 4.3  ********************** 
============================================================
         logLik      AIC      BIC Method Converge
Value -18.16164 42.32327 51.98434     NR     TRUE
============================================================
Variance-Covariance components:
                         VarComp VarCompSE Zratio Constraint
Name.Yield-Yield           2.965    1.5055  1.969   Positive
CA.2011:Name.Yield-Yield  10.424    4.4544  2.340   Positive
CA.2012:Name.Yield-Yield   2.658    1.8032  1.474   Positive
CA.2013:Name.Yield-Yield   5.702    2.5113  2.271   Positive
units.Yield-Yield          4.398    0.6517  6.748   Positive
============================================================
Fixed effects:
  Trait      Effect Estimate Std.Error t.value
1 Yield (Intercept)   16.511    0.8269  19.967
2 Yield  EnvCA.2012   -5.809    0.8593  -6.760
3 Yield  EnvCA.2013   -6.423    0.9358  -6.864
============================================================
Groups and observations:
             Yield
Name            41
CA.2011:Name    41
CA.2012:Name    41
CA.2013:Name    41
============================================================
Use the '$' sign to access results and parameters

I want to ask is it possible to do the same in nlme or lme4?

To be honest I'm surprised that all the variance components in this model are identifiable, but they seem to be (I'll have to think about it).
This is slightly easier in glmmTMB (which has a built-in capability for fitting multivariate RE with diagonal covariance), but can also be hacked without too much trouble in lme4 using the framework described in ?modular:
library(lme4)
library(sommer)
library(glmmTMB)
library(broom.mixed)
data(DT_example)

glmmTMB
fit1 <- glmmTMB(Yield ~ Env + (1|Name) + diag(0 + Env | Name), data = DT_example,
              REML = TRUE)
## variances 
tidy(fit1, effects = "ran_pars", scales = "vcov")

lme4 (modular)
lmod <- lFormula(Yield ~ Env + (1|Name) + (0 + Env | Name), data = DT_example, REML = TRUE)
df <- do.call(mkLmerDevfun, lmod)
## wrapper function: take parameters for a diagonal cov matrix,
##  pass `df()` the values it expects plus zeros for the covariances
df2 <- function(theta) {
    d <- diag(theta[2:4])
    th <- c(theta[1], d[lower.tri(d, diag = TRUE)])
    df(th)
}
df2(c(1,1,1,1))  ## test deviance function
opt <-nloptwrap(c(1,1,1,1), fn = df2, lower = rep(0, 4), upper = rep(Inf, 4))
fit2 <- mkMerMod(environment(df), opt, lmod$reTrms, fr = lmod$fr)
tidy(fit2, effects = "ran_pars", scales = "vcov")


Thank you. May I refer you to another of my question related to nlme/lme4 here for help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/647407/flexible-covariance-structure-of-the-nested-term-in-linear-mixed-model?noredirect=1#comment1212552_647407

May I also ask why you would be concerned that the variance parameters are unidentifiable? Any general rule for identifability to be of concern?
